# compare two comma separated strings

Tags: linux, bash

How can I compare two comma separated strings (master and input) in such a way that if any value of input string matches the value of master string then echo "present" otherwise echo "absent".
For example:

```
master_list="customer,products,address"
input="relations,country,customer"
```

gives echo "present" (since customer is present in both)

```
master_list="customer,products,address"
input="address,customer,car"
```

gives echo "present" (since customer and address are present in both)

```
master_list="customer,products,address"
input="address"
```

gives echo "present" (since address present in both)

```
master_list="customer,products,address"
input="car"
```

gives echo "absent" (since nothing matches)

```
master_list="customer,products,address"
input="humans,car"
```

gives echo "absent" (since nothing matches)

I tried the following:

```
if [[ ",$master_list," =~ ",$input," ]]; then
  echo "present"
else
  echo "absent"
fi
```

but it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do this is through awk:

```
awk -F, -v master=$master_list '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if (master ~ $i) { nomatch=0 } else { nomatch=1 } } } END { if ( nomatch==1 ) { print "absent" } else { print "present" } }' <<< $input
```

Set the field delimiter to , and then pass the master_list variable as master. Take each comma separated value in input and pattern match against the master. If there is a match set nomatch marked to 0 else set it to 1. At the end check the nomatch marker and print present or absent accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a function for this comparison by calling `grep` and `tr` inside:

```
compare() {
   grep -qFxf <(tr ',' '\n' <<< "$2") <(tr ',' '\n' <<< "$1") &&
   echo "present" || echo "absent"
}
```

Then call it as:

```
compare "customer,products,address" "relations,country,customer"
present

compare "customer,products,address" "car"
absent

compare "customer,products,address" "address,customer,car"
present
```